# Prove that $\frac12 \int_0^1 \log(\sin \pi x) dx = \frac{1}{2π} \int_0^\pi \log(\sin x) dx$

Tags: integration

I posted a question earlier but it was closed as duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575644/evaluation-of-the-integral-int-01-log-gammax1-mathrm-dx).

I see the answer and it was pretty much explained. But I got stuck on a step where the answerer put $\frac12 \int_0^1 \log(\sin \pi x) dx = \frac{1}{2π} \int_0^\pi \log(\sin x) dx$

I didn't understand this step. Can anyone prove it? It there any formula? Please don't close my question it's really important for me, I'm trying to solve it from 3 hours.

Comment: See [reverse chain rule substitution method for integration](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/in-in-grade-12-ncert/xd340c21e718214c5:indefinite-integrals/xd340c21e718214c5:reverse-chain-rule/e/integration-by-the-reverse-chain-rule).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let $t = \pi x$ , $x$ is a dummy variable here, so after you perform the substitution change the $t$ back to $x$.

Comment: How the upper bond of integral changed to pi?

Comment: when you introduce a substitution you must also accordingly change the bounds. When $t=\pi x$, plug in the lower bound and upper bounds for the first integral into the substitution. $x=0  \rightarrow t=0 \pi=0 $ and $x=\pi \rightarrow t=1\pi=\pi$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner to integrals and I know only few rules.

Comment: i edited my comment. does this help?

Comment: Yeah, thank you so much!

Comment: @I_am If you are a beginner, first focus on developing your basics. These are advanced integrals and you are definitely not ready for them. I can suggest a book or two, if you want.

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari Yes please

Comment: @I_am A good place to start will be Spivak's Calculus. If you find that one too hard, then Calculus for Dummies.

Answer (score 0):

For a beginner, I want to give a complete solution to a him/her.

Let $y=\pi x$, then $d x=\frac{d y}{\pi}$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \ln (\sin \pi x) d x &=\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi} \ln (\sin y)\left(\frac{d y}{\pi}\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \ln (\sin y) d y \\
&=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \ln (\sin x) d x
\end{aligned}
$$