# Proving $ \int_0^1 \ln(\Gamma (x)) \, dx = \ln \sqrt{2π} $

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, proof-writing

I came across a question in the text book where I had to prove,

$$ \int_0^1 \ln(\Gamma (x)) \, dx = \ln \sqrt{2π} $$

Here's my approach,

$$ I = \int_0^1 \ln(\Gamma (x)) \, dx $$

Also, using $$\int_a^b f(x) \, dx = \int_a^b f(a+b-x) \, dx$$ I get,

$$ I = \int_0^1 \ln \Gamma (1-x) \, dx $$

$$ 2I = \int_0^1 \ln ( \Gamma (x) \Gamma (1-x)) \, dx $$

$$ I = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \ln \bigg[ \dfrac{π}{\sin π x} \bigg] \, dx $$

Now I can use the $ \ln (\frac{a}{b}) $ formula and solve it.

I was wondering, are there any other ways you can show me?

Comment: @Robert Z      Yes! Corrected. It was a typing error. Thanks.

Comment: Then for the last integral see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354795/evaluate-int-0-pi-ln-left-sin-theta-right-d-theta

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167206/calculate-integrals-involving-gamma-function/167215#167215 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529205/evaluating-the-log-gamma-integral-int-0z-log-gamma-x-mathrm-dx-i

Comment: @Robert Z how are you able to find the relevant questions like that? What do you type in the search?

Comment: I use https://approach0.xyz/search/